# Java JFrame нужна помощь

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Reader extends JFrame{
    JButton b1,b2;
    JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4;
    JTextField t1, t2;
    int i, k;
    String a, b;

    public Reader(String s){
        super(s);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        b1 = new JButton("Очистить");
        b2 = new JButton("Посчитать");
        l1 = new JLabel("Введите первое число");
        l2 = new JLabel("Введите второе число");
        l3 = new JLabel("");
        l4 = new JLabel("");
        t1 = new JTextField(10);
        t2 = new JTextField(10);
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(l1);
        add(t1);
        add(l2);
        add(t2);
        add(l3);
        add(l4);
```

Почему команды `JFrame`, `JButton`, `JLabel` показывает как ошибка? и прога не пашет

Comment: >Почему команды JFrame,JButton, JLabel показывает как ошибка? и прога не пашет

какая ошибка? Кто показывает? Что не пашет? Если вам нужна своевременная и грамотная помощь, то пожалуйста формулируйте ваши вопросы точно, грамотно и корректно. Додумывать, что же конкретно у вас не работает, никто за вас не станет

Comment: Абсолютно неясно, что хочется сделать и что не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Мое предположение:

В строках импорта отсутствуют `*`, должно быть так:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

Comment: Скорее всего, звездочки в вопросе исчезли из-за неправильного форматирования.